# Connecting UIView Outlet

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I am trying to connect a UIView as an outlet, so I can call upon it in another ViewController, but it doesn't seem to let me do it. I have tried dragging from the view itself to the code but it won't prompt me with adding a new outlet.

I tried writing the @IBOutlet weak var MyProductsView: UIView! , and then dragging from it to the view and vice versa, but it won't work.

Notice my view is a container view, if it matters.

Notice that on the right, the WelcomeScreen class is of a different view than Product View. I am trying to create a ProductsView outlet in the WelcomeScreen class.

Thanks in advance !

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you've set the class's name of your view controller to "WelcomeScreen" from the storyboard?

Comment: Welcome Screen is my other view, not the one presented in the picture

Comment: And yes, I'm sure... When I click the view in the Main.storyboard, it shows me the WelcomeScreen class automatically

Comment: It doesn't matter what shows you Xcode automatically. Xcode can show you wrong class by mistake. So you should check the class of the vc presented in the picture from the storyboard, and open that class manually.

Comment: The view in the picture is of class "ProductView", and the view I want to have access to it via outlet is "Welcome Screen". both views are of the correct class as shown under "Custom Class" under Identity inspector

Comment: Dear MathEnthusiast, "view" and "view controller" are different things. I'm not about view but ViewController

Comment: I think then that my UIView isn't assigned a UIView custom class. So that's the reason ? Someone gave me an example of an existing outlet and the button working on it, but the container view isn't assigned a custom class...